# How can I set a username alias in github commits?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I just finished a semester at college and decided to import all of my projects from bitbucket (required for my classes) to github (where all of my other projects are). I successfully imported them. Unfortunately, at the time when I was working on these projects, I was switching between three different computers.

As a result, the commit history has lots of different names for commits that I did myself. I'd like to set an "alias" like you can in bitbucket, saying "these three people are also me." Is this possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 6):

Navigate to Setting->Emails (or directly to https://github.com/settings/emails), and just add the emails you used on your "unattributed" commits.