# Does GitHub support some kind of alias feature?

Tags: git, github

I've had a GitHub account (paid) for several years which I use under my company name (also my login name) which I started when I was working for myself. Since then, I've hired on with another firm and I'm working with a contractor where I need to submit issues and such to his project.

The problem is, I'd like to be able to submit issues to other projects under an alias name, but still be able to use my current account and not have to open up a separate account. I don't think it would look good for me to work for company A while using the name of company B.

I saw this post, but I can't tell if doing this means when I post issues, which name would show up in the other user's account.

[How can I set a username alias in github commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948001/how-can-i-set-a-username-alias-in-github-commits)

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: You could create an organization on github. I think you can push and pull and make pull requests as an organization, and you can name it anything you like. If you are on the github portal, you just click the plus sign and then "New Organization".

Comment: I was a bit confused when I looked at that, still am. If I click for a "new org", it will disable all my private repos. I'm already paying a year fee for just myself. Yet if I click the next plan up, it's $25 a month. The plans aren't making sense to me, nor what happens with my current repos.